# Sony Xperia Z1 status bar issue

Tags: notification-bar, sony-xperia-z1

I have a Sony Xperia Z1 that suddenly decided not to react when I pull down the status bar.

I restarted my mobile and also tried to use the developer options to show touches, but it still didn't work.

When using the developer options on Nexus 4, the Y coordinate changes from 0 to over 1k. On Xperia Z1, the Y starts from 87 and then moves as it should be downwards.

Aka. the touches over the status bar is not registered in the device... Any idea why?

Comment: What happens if you rotate the device (in an app that supports rotation)? Does the status bar work in landscape mode? If it still doesn't work, then you know your physical screen is fine and something has gone wrong in software.

Comment: Didnt work in landscape but certanly a good point.

Answer (score 1):

This suddenly solved itself :

What i did is to enable developer settings and suddenly it started working after about 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Just install from "play store" the free application "DropDownStusBar", it worked for me.

Comment: Are you the developer of this app, or just a happy customer? It would be helpful to add a link: that way, any visitors can be sure of getting the app you mean.